# QMessageBox without Icon

Tags: windows, qt, qmessagebox

Normally, when creating a `QMessageBox`, the window icon will look like this:

[image]

But I want to have a `QMessageBox` without the  window/title bar icon, like this:

[image]

I did some research and saw that I have to use `QMessageBox::NoIcon`. I tried, but it did not really work out.

So what can I do to remove the `QMessageBox` icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QMessageBox::NoIcon` is not for the title bar icon: it's for the big icon in your message box.

In order to remove the title bar icon, you have to set specific flags:

```
QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Question,
        "This is the title",
        "This is the text",
        QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this);

// set the flags you want: here is the case when you want to keep the close button
msgBox.setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);

msgBox.exec();
```